# Banner when voting for answers while not logged in is too wide in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, voting, mobile-web

Voting for answers not being logged into site in mobile web leads to apperance of screen-wide banner. E.g. ELL:

> [image: toooooo long]

Voting on question looks fine:

> [image: vote on question]